# Partitioning. Arch vs Ubuntu manuals

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, partition

I got a little confused after I had read advices on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning and on https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/directory-tree.html. Why is there such a big difference between the sizes of the partitions? E.g., about / partition.

**Ubuntu.**

> Typically 150–250MB is needed for the root partition.

**Arch.**

> 15-20 GB should be sufficient for most users with modern hard disks.

Comment: "Needed" != "sufficient for most users"...

Comment: @vonbrand, by the way, I followed [the Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/directory-tree.html) once. E.g., 200 MB wasn't enough for installing a package and I had to re-install the system. Why? Is the guide wrong?

Comment: @Marksim Dmitriev You may have needed the full 250MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest difference is due to this in Arch:

> The root filesystem (`/`) **must** contain the `/usr` directory

`/usr` can grow quite a bit depending on what you install. Ubuntu supports (and recommends in that document) that `/usr` be on a separate partition, so `/` doesn't have to be very large.

Comment: @RedPlanet I'll vote up for you